# Javascript string interpolation in object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a function that pushes an object into array "messages" as shown below:

```
getMessages() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.numberOfMessages; i++) {
        this.messages.push({ label: "CUSTOMER.MESSAGE_CHOICE.MSGx.LABEL", value: "CUSTOMER.MESSAGE_CHOICE.MSGx.VALUE" });
    }
}
```

I'd like to have variable "i" from my for loop instead of "x" in my

```
"CUSTOMER.MESSAGE_CHOICE.MSGx.LABEL" and "CUSTOMER.MESSAGE_CHOICE.MSGx.VALUE".
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Did you try concatenating the string? Or using template strings? It's not exactly rocket science...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `template` **literals**.

> Template literals are string literals allowing embedded expressions.
>   You can use multi-line strings and string interpolation features with
>   them. They were called "template strings" in prior editions of the
>   ES2015 specification.

```
getMessages() {
   for (let i = 0; i < this.numberOfMessages; i++) {
    this.messages.push({ label: `CUSTOMER.MESSAGE_CHOICE.MSG${i}.LABEL`, value: `CUSTOMER.MESSAGE_CHOICE.MSG${i}.VALUE` });
   }
}
```